# How to deploy Django (via Anaconda) to Heroku with django_heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, anaconda

I am trying to deploy my first Django application to Heroku. I'm using anaconda for  python, and following [Deploying Python from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python), and the recommendation is to use django_heroku package.

I cannot find this package and get the following message when using: 
`conda install django_heroku.`

Does anyone know where this package is? Is this necessary, or is there another way?

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - django_heroku

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Install it with `pip` instead? Did you follow their [Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) guide? I didn't have a problem installing everything with pip, since they recommend using `pipenv` to set up a virtual environment.